# Таймер php,js,mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Выводится время из БД:

```
<span   id="time" name="time" class="large pull-right"><small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></small> <?=$r->last_time?></span>
```

Каждую секунду время читается заново

```
setInterval(function(){$('#time').load('core/check.php #timel');},500);
```

Можно ли как-то сделать,что бы таймер после каждой секунды отнимал в БД - 1 секунду и если к примеру произошли изменения  прибавилось 10 секунд то он прибавлял эти секунды,а не продолжал работать?

Comment: Я бы вам рекомендовал собраться с мыслями и сформулировать, описать свой вопрос более разборчиво и понятнее для остальных. Потому, что сейчас из вопроса ничего не ясно. И еще.. каждую секунду обращаться к БД от одного пользователя - не лучшая идея.... или вы там атаку организуете?

Comment: как бы это объяснить, я пытаюсь сделать аукцион и время для лота берется из базы данных.система такова,что после ставки прибавляется 10 секунд ко времени,вот нужно,что бы таймер отсчитывал все секунды до конца и если время равно 0 то менял видимость лота.

Comment: А почему бы не класть в базу сразу время окончания лота. И время посекундно отсчитывать прямо на клиенте отдавая ему разово скрипт с уже вычисленным остатком времени до нужного события. Если клиент будет считать долго можно предусмотреть редкую синхронизацию времени с сервером.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понял, что очень сложно исходя из вопроса, то можно использовать вот эту php функцию, которую необходимо внести в файл check.php, в БД нужно хранить дату окончания лота, подгружаем её и используя функцию подсчитываем сколько времени осталось. Но, как уже было сказано выше, обращаться к БД каждую секунду не очень хорошая идея.

```
<?php
function timeLeft($date)
{
    $seconds = strtotime($date) - time();

    $days = floor($seconds / 86400);
    $seconds %= 86400;

    $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
    $seconds %= 3600;

    $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
    $seconds %= 60;

    if ($days) {
        return "{$days}д {$hours}ч";
    }
    if ($hours) {
        return "{$hours}ч {$minutes}м"; 
    }
    if ($minutes) {
        return "{$minutes}м {$seconds}с";
    }
    return "{$seconds}с";
}
?>

<span id="time" name="time" class="large pull-right"><small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></small> <?php echo timeLeft($r->last_time); ?></span>
```